# Тире в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли здесь поставить тире перед словами "таким образом"? Очень хочется как-то отделить эту часть предложения от всего остального...

В настоящее время наше предприятие успешно завершило монтаж и пуско-наладку оборудования: двух токарно-карусельно-фрезерных обрабатывающих центров Hankook, горизонтально-расточного обрабатывающего центра с ЧПУ, изготовленного специально для завода ООО «УЗТПА» компанией Tos Varnsdorf, второго сварочного комплекса PEMA, испытательного стенда Ventill и покрасочной камеры; завершена разработка и запущена в серийное производство линейка шаровых кранов диаметром Ду 700 – Ду 1200,(–) таким образом, в настоящее время предприятие «УЗТПА» вышло на серийное производство всех типоразмеров шаровых кранов диаметром от Ду 10 до Ду 1200 мм.

Или лучше разбить это предложение на два и "таким образом" начать с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обобщающее слово "оборудования" и двоеточие за ним лучше убрать; точку с запятой заменить на точку и начать новое предложение; перед "таким образом" тоже поставить точку и начать новое предложение. После этих правок ваш текст перестанет походить на французский роман 18-19 века и станет нормальным техническим текстом. )))